# JavaScript doesn't work after JSP page redirect....Any solution?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

Here is the code:

```
<%
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try
{
    con = DataSource.getInstance().getConnection();
    String sql = "select userid,password from users where userid=? and password=?";
    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1, username);
    pstmt.setString(2, password);
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    if(!rs.isBeforeFirst())
    {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        %>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var x = document.getElementById("errorbox");
            alert(x);
            x.style.display = "block";
            x.innerHTML = "Ooops...User doesn't exist!!";
        </script>
        <%
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

And here is the directory structure of the project..

```
WebContent  
|  
|---Meta-Inf  
|  
|---resources  
|      |____CSS  
|      |____JS  
|      |____images  
|---Web-Inf  
|  
|-----login.jsp  
|-----verify.jsp
```

Resources file contains css,js and images folders to store css,javascript and image resources. All .jsp files are under WebContent directory.

When user can't be authenticated, I use sendRedirect("login.jsp") and on that page i have div element, whose display property is set to none. So i want to use JavaScript to set property to display:block. But JavaScript is not working after redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript code is bound to one webpage.

When you send the Javascript code in your code example, you are adding it to the page that you currently build in JSP, which in this case is the `verify.jsp` (I suppose). The browser then receives this code and the request to redirect the user to `login.jsp`.

When it does so, the `verify.jsp` page gets unloaded, and with it all Javascript code that was included in it. If you want Javascript code to be executed on your destination page, `login.jsp`, you have to add it in this page.

If you want to keep the verification and the rendering of the login page in to different files, you will have to include the information, that the previous login failed, in the URL you're redirecting to, e.g.:

```
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?loginfailed=1");
```

and check for this in the `login.jsp`:

```
if (request.getParameter("loginfailed") == "1") {
    %>
    <div id="errorbox">
        Ooops...User doesn't exist!!
    </div>
    <%
}
```